# Error invalid_request when trying to create BigQuery data export from YouTube

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, youtube, youtube-data-api, data-transfer

I am trying to add a YouTube Data Export To my BigQuery account:

[[image]]

When I click SAVE, I choose the right channel and click Allow for data access:

[image]

And then I get this error

[image]

```
Error 400: invalid_request
Account restricted

The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable billing on your project? Do you have a billing problem?

Comment: Billing is ok. The reporting works for another YT channel I have, it is not working for this specific secondary channel

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed to setting up a Youtube Channel, There are required permissions to your gcp account. [Required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/youtube-channel-transfer#:%7E:text=the%20YouTube%20data.-,Required%20permissions,-Creating%20a%20YouTube).

BigQuery needs the following Identity and Access Management permissions:

- `bigquery.transfers.update` to create the transfer
- `bigquery.datasets.get` and `bigquery.datasets.update` on the target data set.
- If you intend to set up transfer run notifications for Pub/Sub, you must have `pubsub.topics.setIamPolicy` permissions. Pub/Sub permissions are not required if you just set up email notifications. For more information, see [BigQuery Data Transfer Service run notifications](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-run-notifications).

  The `bigquery.admin` predefined IAM role includes all of the BigQuery permissions that you need to create a YouTube Channel transfer. For more information about IAM roles in BigQuery, see [Predefined roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/youtube-channel-transfer#:%7E:text=Predefined%20roles%20and%20permissions)

Comment: I believe the permissions are ok, because if I choose a different YT Channel of the same user the integration works. It is working for one of my channels, but not the other channel.

Answer (score 0):

You can only start processing a transfer run with a YouTube [`Brand account`](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7001996) which is associated with **one (and only one)** YouTube Channel.

You can check how many branding accounts you have [here](https://myaccount.google.com/brandaccounts). Also your branded accounts are only [limited](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9367690?hl=en) only to YouTube.
Assuming from your screenshots , after clicking on save I believe you are signing in using a YouTube channel name , that is not [supported](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/165556?hl=en#:%7E:text=As%20we%20integrate%20services%20across,Google%20Accounts%20with%20YouTube%20usernames.) any more.

Comment: I have different brand accounts, and each one of them with only one youtube channel. All these channels work for export to BQ, except the one I mentioned. It is the only channel market as (limited to YouTube) in the brand accounts page. How to fix it?

Comment: I am not sure how you can remove the `Limited to YouTube` tag in a brand account . My best guess is you might need to move your channel to some other gmail account which does not have any channel to it. It's better to take help from [YouTube support](https://support.google.com/youtube)